How Can I Obtain Steam achievements in a Tyranobuilder game?
I am trying to run achievement acquired commands for Steam.
I know it is pretty easy with Python like this :
$ achievement.grant("ACH_ID")
$ achievement.Sync()

However I have built a game using Tyranobuilder and I want to publish on Steam. I have no idea how I can run a similar achievement code. I need your help with this please.

https://steamcommunity.com/app/345370/discussions/0/385428943465156590/
